# How does slow resistance work?

Tags: torchlight-2

The spell "Willpower" can be learned and at level 6 it provides a 50% resistance to slow and immobilization effects.

Does this mean:
A)  50% of the time you are not slowed when you otherwise would be
B)  You are only slowed for 50% of the normal duration
C)  Your speed is only slowed by half the amount it normally would be

I am guessing that immobilization resistance works the same way as slow, so the most likely answer would be A) if that is the case.

Follow-up question:  Does the slow resistance from this ability apply to all effects that slow, such as monsters with the Freezing keyword?

Follow-up question:  Does knockback resistance work the same way?

Comment: I'm not an expert, but since it gives 50% resistance to **both**, it sounds like it would reduce the time of the effect.  It doesn't make sense that you would be less immobilized than you already are.   But I don't know this for fact, and its not documented.

Comment: Well, a 50% reduction of the duration makes sense, but it could be a 50% chance to not be slowed.  Similar to how blocking works in TL2.

Comment: I don't really have a clue.  I've had issues finding information like that for TL2.  I'd recommend testing it for yourself at this point.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is A. 50% of the time the spells won't work on you at all.

Comment: Can you cite evidence of this?

Answer (score -2):

This is just a guess, but it's a fairly educated one. I've played more than a few games with crowd control in them. The way it usually works is the percentage of the resist is the chance of you actually resisting the crowd control effect. so a 10% poison resist should protect you from poison roughly one in ten times. Hope I answered your question.